# Get the end date of last quarter

Tags: java, date

For a given date, how to get the end date of last quarter? I need to run a job, which takes this into account. 
EDIT: 1st quarter is Jan, Feb, Mar; 2nd is Apr, May, June, so on;

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you defining "quarter"?

Comment: Would that be a fiscal quarter, or a calendar quarter?  Do you have 90 day quarters or 91 day quarters?  What date do you typically start your business year?  If that happens to be a holiday, do you need to adjust the date?  The question is concise, but it requires a lot of missing information to be answered.

Comment: 1st quarter is Jan, Feb, Mar; 2nd is Apr, May, June, so on;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Quarter based on Weeks in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861418/find-quarter-based-on-weeks-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically:

1. Figure out which is the current quarter
2. Return the last date of the previous quarter (March 31, June 30, September 30, December 31)

So to figure out which is the current quarter:
`int quarter = (myDate.getMonth() / 3) + 1;`
(Note that [getMonth()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth%28%29) is deprecated in favor of `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`.)

Then match the previous quarter to a date.

```
int prevQuarter = (myDate.getMonth() / 3); 
switch(prevQuarter) {
    case 3 : 
        // return September 30
    case 2 :
        // return June 30
    case 1 :
        // return March 31
    case 0 : default :
        // return December 31
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well quarters only end in months 12,9,6 and 3. all of these have a static length. so there are only 4 valid end dates. compare your month and if it is 1 or 2 or 3, answer is 31.12 of year-1 , if it is 4,5,6 it is 31.3 of this year, if it is 7,8,9 it is 30.6 of this year. if it is 10.11.12 it is 30.9 this year.

Comment: This ofcourse assumes that you are talking about business quarters.

Comment: do the start + end dates of the quarters never change? I know leap-days are added to February, but do the other months ever change # of days? (And why haven't I ever noticed/wondered this before)

Comment: i dont think they ever change, sometimes leap seconds are added to december but that never adds days

Answer (score 0):

http://www.taggercat.com/docs/api/TaggerCat/com/taggercat/util/DateUtils.html#last90Days%28%29

```
public static java.util.Date[] last90Days()
```

Returns the two dates that represent the start and end of the last quarter

Returns: the two dates that represent this period

This would help, using these dates and the date given, you can determine the date of the last quarter.  If I'm understanding your question correctly that is.

Comment: I think the OP is saying for a given date. It does not seem to take any date argument.

Comment: So are you saying that he doesn't have a Date object?

Comment: It's not clear what he wants exactly. Might be he needs find the laste date of the quarter for the a given date. But not sure, his question is just not clear enough to be answered.