# Get start and end dates of years quarters

Tags: php, date

does anyone know, how to get the start and end dates of the quarters of a year?
Basically I need start and end dates of the current quarter and the following 3 quarters.

I have a dropdown and it´s dates should be filled dynamically to look like this:

```
<select name="quarter-selection">
        <option value="2012-07-01,2012-09-31">Q3 2012</option>
        <option value="2012-10-01,2012-12-31">Q4 2012</option>
        <option value="2013-01-01,2013-03-31">Q1 2013</option>
        <option value="2013-04-01,2013-06-30">Q2 2013</option>
    </select>
```

Any help highly appreciated.
thx,
Florian

Comment: Jan 1st, Apr 1st, Jun 1st and Sep 1st? How dynamic are your quarters?

Comment: Please write more  about your issue :)

Comment: hey, I answered this question already ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954960/get-the-end-date-of-last-quarter/10955067#10955067

Comment: Do you need the quarter to start form current date ??

Comment: ja current date/current quarter would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it easly with this :

```
$q1 = array(
    'start' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2012)),
    'end' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2012)), 2012))
);
$q2 = array(
    'start' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2012)),
    'end' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2012)), 2012))
);
$q3 = array(
    'start' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2012)),
    'end' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2012)), 2012]))
);
$q4 = array(
    'start' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 2012)),
    'end' => date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2012)), 2012))
);
```

Comment: Yes but his first question was how to find it, so i give him the solution :)

Comment: @deceze Omg I just realized what you meant I was trying to make code generate this. You don't even have to account for a leap year! `face-palm`

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ThreeTen-Extra

The ThreeTen-Extra project extends the java.time classes with additional functionality. This includes the [`Quarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) and [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) classes.

### `YearQuarter`

Determining a quarter means determining a date. Determining a date means specifying a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.now( z );
```

You can do math, adding and subtracting.

```
YearQuarter yqNext = yq.plusQuarters( 1 );
```

### `LocalDate`

You can interrogate for the first and last dates of that quarter, to get `LocalDate` objects. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate firstDay = yq.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate lastDay = yq.atEndOfQuarter();
```

To generate a String that represents the `LocalDate` value in standard ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) simply call `toString`.

```
String output = firstDay.toString();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.